# Having issues with a quick POST request for a token

Tags: json, swift, api, post, networking

So I'm trying to do a quick and dirty post request to get a token but I keep
getting this error. All I want to do for right now is print the JSON so I know I can at least test the app.

```
    <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600002990600> { URL: https://development-290808.ew.r.appspot.com/token } { Status Code: 422, Headers {
    "Alt-Svc" =     (
        "h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\""
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        172
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Wed, 16 Dec 2020 00:10:14 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        "Google Frontend"
    );
    "x-cloud-trace-context" =     (
        "a71f62144e6ce9a6c7046d700a6bad7a;o=1"
    );
} }
{
    detail =     (
                {
            loc =             (
                body,
                username
            );
            msg = "field required";
            type = "value_error.missing";
        },
                {
            loc =             (
                body,
                password
            );
            msg = "field required";
            type = "value_error.missing";
        }
    );
}
```

With this code

```
func getToken() {
    
    let parameters = ["username" : "Zach", "password" : "Password"]
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://development-290808.ew.r.appspot.com/token") else { return }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else {
        return }
    request.httpBody = httpBody
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
        
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error)
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }.resume()
    
}
```

}

And because stack overflow doesn't like it when you post mostly code and little txt, here I am adding more text so I can post this question.

Comment: Well, the reason: your code is "quick&dirty" ;)   So, improve that. Use proper error handling. Code shall only move to the next statement if ALL prerequisites are fulfilled. Then, maybe your server doesn't like application/json, maybe it expects a particular JSON, which you didn't sent. Look up the docs. ;) The status code 422 indicates that it may accept application/json, but your JSON may not be exactly what  it wants.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be an issue with the request body.. your server looks to be expecting something different. Check spelling and fields on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You are using guard statement on http body, and it does not fails, but that http body is wrong, and you are not sending any params to backend, and as error says value is missing, try without guard force unwrap it(in debug purpose) and app will crash and you will get error what is wrong that part.